# How can i center text while increasing icon size in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

[image][image]

When i try to increase icon size and text content is not align into center how can i do this and i am using react-native-vector-icons and i want text center like drafts image

```
<Text>Lorem <Icon name="ios-book" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" /> Ipsum</Text>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap it in a `View` like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text> Lorem Ipsum </Text>
    <Icon name="ios-book" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />
</View>
```

You can test it [**here**](https://snack.expo.io/H1-OlboLG), note that I've used a `View` instead of `Icon` just for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<View style = {{alignItems:'center',}}>
      <Text style = {{alignSelf: 'center'}}>Lorem 
      <Icon name="ios-book" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" style = {{alignSelf:'center'}} /> Ipsum</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: sorry but No change text  still not into the center

Comment: Try put in the style of the text  {{textAlign : 'center' }}

Comment: by using this both  icon and text are into the center of content

Comment: And isn't that what you want?

Comment: Try both properties, `textAlign: center` and `justifyContent: center`